# About toml line break in dependencies of Cargo.toml

Tags: rust-cargo, toml

I write dependencies of Cargo.toml :

```
[dependencies ]
opencv = {version = "0.26", default-features = false, features = ["opencv-41"]}
```

Above one line can pass compilation.

I want to seperate lines for dependencies.

This page 
https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml-test/blob/master/tests/valid/multiline-string.toml

said solution.

I refer this solution to write my dependencies:

```
[dependencies ]
opencv = """\{version = "0.26", \
default-features = false, \
features = ["opencv-41"] \
}"""
```

But compiler throw error:

```
$ cargo build                                          [±master ●]

error: failed to parse manifest at /home/curlywei/WorkSpace/rust/testcargo/Cargo.toml

Caused by:
  failed to parse the version requirement { version = "0.26", default-features = false, features = ["opencv-41"] } for dependency opencv

Caused by:
  the given version requirement is invalid
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your link contains examples of multiline *strings*, not tables. In TOML, inline tables may not contain newlines.

Instead, the TOML [spec](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#inline-table) suggests using a regular table:

> No newlines are allowed between the curly braces unless they are valid within a value. Even so, it is strongly discouraged to break an inline table onto multiples lines. If you find yourself gripped with this desire, it means you should be using standard tables.

```
[dependencies.opencv]
version = "0.26"
default-features = false
features = ["opencv-41"]
```